# Literature on transformed Gaussian matrices

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, random-matrices

I am considering real $n$-by-$m$ matrices of the following type:

$$
M=SM^\prime,\\
M^\prime_{ij} \overset{\text{iid}} \sim N(0,1).
$$

Here, $S$ is a fixed $n$-by-$n$ matrix and the entries of $M^\prime$ (same size as $M$) are just i.i.d Gaussian. It is important that the considered matrices are rectangular and not simply square. $S$ can be identity but, ideally, should be an arbitrary full-rank matrix.

As far as I know, in the special case of $S=I, n=m$ this construction is called the [real Ginibre ensemble](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5913966_Eigenvalue_Statistics_of_the_Real_Ginibre_Ensemble). Can anyone suggest some literature/references for the more general case? I'm particularly interested in spectral properties of these matrices such as singular value/vector distributions.

Answer (score 1):

A very obvious thing was pointed out to me: my case is covered by the [Wishart ensemble](https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/386/ClassicalEnsembles.pdf). That is, the singular values of $M$ are, by definition, simply the square roots of the eigenvalues of $MM^T$, which is precisely what the Wishart ensemble is.